# Laravel - Artisan error with custom storage directory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have some troubles running artisan commands in my Laravel project.

I had to change the storage directory location in my project and now, when I try to run any artisan command, it output this error :

```
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"file_put_contents(\/meta\/services.json):
failed to open stream: No such file or directory"
```

I changed the storage path in the `bootstrap/path.php` file and the application works just fine. (I can see the view, logs, sessions generated in my custom storage directory)

But artisan cannot find the `storage/meta/services.json` file. 
I checked and the file exists in my storage directory.

If I create a `storage/meta` directory in the `/app`folder it's working, but I need to use a custom storage directory.

Does artisan need a special configuration file? Am I missing something?

Thanks.

This is what contains my path file:

```
'app' => 'C:/wamp/www/myproject/app/',
'public' => 'C:/wamp/www/myproject/public',
'base' => __DIR__.'/..',
'storage' => 'C:/wamp/www/storage',
```

Comment: No, it just works. Show your `paths.php` file.

Comment: I would check permissions for this directory then.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using laravels storage_path() function to determine the path?

Before creating the file, maybe do:

```
$path = storage_path() . '/meta';

if (!File::exists($path)) {
    File::makeDirectory($path, $mode = 0755, true, true);
}
```